# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array

Tags: php, function

The users on the application are logged in by their e-mail. This e-mail is in a session. With this session I try to get more information of that user to print out there (sur)names and the avatar. When I do it in my navbar he's doing it all well but on the page itself it gives the following error:  **'Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array'**

What am i doing wrong?

PHP:

```
$user = new User();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$user->getUserInfoByEmail($email);
var_dump($user['avatar']);
```

FUNCTION:

```
public function getUserInfoByEmail($email)
{
    $db = new Db();
    $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE email = '" . $_SESSION["email"] . "';";
    $result = $db->conn->query($select);
    return $data=$result->fetch_assoc();

}
```

Comment: The only error is in the var_dump, you are trying to access Object as an array. And now I see, that the answer was already added. So have a look at it and it's self-explanatory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is because you are using the `$user` object as an array (as the error message makes *perfectly* clear).

Change:

```
var_dump($user['avatar']);
```

To this:

```
var_dump($user->avatar);
```

Comment: It's giving me 'null' as result.. but I don't get it. I'm doing exactly the same on the other place en that's working perfectly?

Comment: @MarnixVerhulst If it gives you `null` then maybe it is because it actually is `null`? It can also be because `avatar` does not exist in the object. Try to `var_dump($user);` and see if the `avatar` property is defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... Its working now :) sorry i didn't check that